# Math commands and errors in discord.py

Tags: python, math, discord, discord.py

I have several math commands in my discord.py bot. However, I want to do something like the bot says 'You cannot calculate words!' or in division command it could say 'second number cannot be zero!'.

I tried using **If** and **Else** statements, as well as **Try** and **Except** statements but they do not work.
I want to detect if it is actually a float or an integer or a string. if it is a string, it should say something like 'You cannot calculate words!' as mentioned above.

Also in division command, it should say something like 'second number cannot be zero!' as mentioned above.

Here is my code

```
@bot.command()
async def add(ctx, num1 : float, num2 : float):
  answer = num1 + num2

  ans_em = discord.Embed(title = 'Addition', description = f'Question: {num1} + {num2}\n\nAnswer: {answer}', colour = discord.Colour.from_rgb(13, 255, 251))
  await ctx.send(embed = ans_em)

@bot.command()
async def sub(ctx, num1 : float, num2 : float):
  answer = num1 - num2

  ans_em = discord.Embed(title = 'Subtraction', description = f'Question: {num1} - {num2}\n\nAnswer: {answer}', colour = discord.Colour.from_rgb(255, 13, 17))

  await ctx.send(embed = ans_em)


@bot.command()
async def div(ctx, num1 : float, num2 : float):
  answer = num1 / num2

  ans_em = discord.Embed(title = 'Addition', description = f'Question: {num1} / {num2}\n\nAnswer: {answer}', colour = discord.Colour.from_rgb(252, 252, 0))
  
  await ctx.send(embed = ans_em)

@bot.command()
async def mul(ctx, num1 : float, num2 : float):
  answer = num1 * num2

  ans_em = discord.Embed(title = 'Addition', description = f'Question: {num1} * {num2}\n\nAnswer: {answer}', colour = discord.Colour.from_rgb(0, 255, 26))

  await ctx.send(embed = ans_em)

@bot.command()
async def avg(ctx, num1 : float, num2 : float):
  answer = (num1 + num2)/2

  ans_embed = discord.Embed(title = 'Average', description = f'Question: Average of {num1} and {num2}\n\nAnswer: {answer}', colour = discord.Colour.blurple())

  await ctx.send(embed = ans_embed)
```

Also, can i do something like the bot says, 'You must have atleast two numbers' in add, sub, mul, div command when there is only one or no numbers at all?

To test those commands, You can join [This Discord Server](https://discord.gg/RDtmjTz87H).
It's just a test sever.

If that link does not work, Use https://discord.gg/RDtmjTz87H

Comment: what's wrong with `if num2 == 0:`?

Comment: See the [Error Handling](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html#error-handling) documentation for `@bot.command`

Comment: You see, `if num == 0;` does not work as by default those numbers are taken as strings. I want to identify if they are string or a float or an integer. How do I identify floats or integers from a string?

Comment: I did see the documentation, So I still don't understand what to do. Could you explain what to use? Also give me the code maybe. I also tried using CheckFailure, but it didn't work. I think I did not understand CheckFailure properly.

Comment: They shouldn't be taken as strings. `@bot.command` is supposed to convert them to the type specified in the function's type annotations.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with discord.py to write the solution myself.

Comment: if you defined `num1 : float, num2 : float` then `discord` should check type and generate error which you should catch with functions which will have decorators `@add.error` `@sub.error` `@div.error`, `@mul.erro`, `@avg.error`. And if something doesn't work then first you could use `print()` and `print(type())` to see what you have in variables and which part of code is executed - it is called `"print debuging"` - or you should write it in log file because `discord` may catch some errors and hide them.

Comment: and` if num == 0;` can't work because it has to be soemthing like `if num2 == 0: print("wrong value") else: ... code...`

Comment: `do not work` is the most useless information. If you get error messages then you should show it in question. We can't run your code and we can't read in your mind - so you have to put all details in question (not in comment) as text (not image)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you define `num1:float, num2;float` then it should check if you get `float` and then you may only use decorator like `@div.error` to catch this error and display some message

```
@bot.command()
async def div(ctx, num1:float, num2:float):
    answer = num1 / num2

    ans_em = discord.Embed(title='Addition', description=f'Question: {num1} / {num2}\n\nAnswer: {answer}', colour=discord.Colour.from_rgb(252, 252, 0))

    await ctx.send(embed=ans_em)

@div.error
async def div_error(ctx, error):
    await ctx.send(error)
```

If you need some details then you can check error type

```
@div.error
async def div_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.BadArgument):
        await ctx.send('[BadArgument] ' + str(error))
    
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandInvokeError):
        await ctx.send('[CommandInvokeError] ' + str(error))

    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send('It needs two values')
```

But it can be more usefull to get values as strings and convert to `float()` with `try/except` to have better control.

```
@bot.command()
async def div(ctx, num1, num2):
    try:
        num1 = float(num1)
    except:
        await ctx.send(f"Can't convert to float: '{num1}'")
        return

    try:
        num2 = float(num2)
    except:
        await ctx.send(f"Can't convert to floai: '{num2}'")
        return
    
    if num2 == 0:
        await ctx.send("Can't divide by zero")
        return
        
    answer = num1 / num2

    ans_em = discord.Embed(title='Addition', description=f'Question: {num1} / {num2}\n\nAnswer: {answer}', colour=discord.Colour.from_rgb(252, 252, 0))
  
    await ctx.send(embed=ans_em)
```

---

You may also use both methods - second method to convert values and first method to catch missing values

```
@div.error
async def div_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send('It needs two values')
```

---

Full working code which I used for tests.

```
# https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html#error-handling
# https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#ext-commands-api-errors
# https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.on_command_error

import os
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

@bot.event
async def on_connect():
    print("Connected as", bot.user.name)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Ready as", bot.user.name)

### div ###

@bot.command()
async def div(ctx, num1:float, num2:float):
    answer = num1 / num2

    ans_em = discord.Embed(title='Addition', description=f'Question: {num1} / {num2}\n\nAnswer: {answer}', colour=discord.Colour.from_rgb(252, 252, 0))
  
    await ctx.send(embed=ans_em)

@div.error
async def div_error(ctx, error):
    print(error)
    print(type(error))
    print(dir(error))
    print(error.args)
    
    if isinstance(error, commands.BadArgument):
        await ctx.send('[BadArgument] ' + str(error))
    
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandInvokeError):
        await ctx.send('[CommandInvokeError] ' + str(error))

    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send('It needs two values')

    #print(dir(ctx))
    print(ctx.args)
    print(ctx.message)

### div2 ###
    
@bot.command()
async def div2(ctx, num1, num2):
    try:
        num1 = float(num1)
    except:
        await ctx.send(f"Can't convert to float: '{num1}'")
        return

    try:
        num2 = float(num2)
    except:
        await ctx.send(f"Can't convert to floai: '{num2}'")
        return
    
    if num2 == 0:
        await ctx.send("Can't divide by zero")
        return
        
    answer = num1 / num2

    ans_em = discord.Embed(title='Addition', description=f'Question: {num1} / {num2}\n\nAnswer: {answer}', colour=discord.Colour.from_rgb(252, 252, 0))
  
    await ctx.send(embed=ans_em)

@div2.error
async def div2_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send('It needs two values')
    #print(error)

@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    print('[on_command_error] error:', error)
    print('[on_command_error] ctx:', ctx)
     
bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the type() keyword to find the type of variables, then check for your cases.

ex.

```py
num = 0
print(type(num))
```

would return `<class 'int'>`